# Android animation between fragments

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am doing an animation between two `Activities` using:

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
    myView, transitionName);
startActivity(myIntent, options.toBundle());
```

and the animation works perfectly. I would like to create the same effect except transitioning between two `Fragments`. Right now I'm using:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
```

but the animation doesn't look the same. Is there a default animation between the fragments that acts the same or is there a way to pass `ActivityOptions` into the fragment transaction?

Answer (score 0):

To animate beetween fragments, you can use animations resources. Try this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
ft.replace(resId, fragment).commit();
```

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) to now more about animation resources.